# pivot rows certain values to columns

Tags: sql, oracle

i have this table,

```
id activity type      start_date
1  a        type_o    01/01/20
1  b        type_o    05/01/20
1  c        type_o    07/01/20
1  d        type_o    23/01/20
1  e        type_o    24/01/20
2  a        type_k    08/01/20
2  b        type_k    10/01/20
2  c        type_k    11/01/20
2  d        type_k    12/01/20
3  a        type_h    12/01/20
3  c        type_h    13/01/20
3  e        type_h    14/01/20
```

all activities are (a,b,c,d,e) 
i want it to look like this,

```
id type     a         b         c         d         e 
1  type_o   01/01/20  05/01/20  07/01/20  23/01/20  24/01/20
2  type_k   08/01/20  10/01/20  11/01/20  null      null 
3  type_h   12/01/20  null      13/01/20  null      12/01/20
```

where we compensate null in other activities not exists in some id's, 
i don't understand the pivot keyword in sql, any help ?

Answer (score 0):

You must be looking for this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE)
PIVOT
(MAX(START_DATE) as START_DATE FOR ACTIVITY IN ('a' as a, 'b' as b, 'c' as c, 'd' as d, 'e' as e))
```

Answer (score 0):

A more universal solution is to use CASE - WHEN statements.

The advantage is - the code is more portable across different SQL flavours and you can take care of duplicates in the records, if needed down the line.

```
select id,type
,case when activity = 'a' then  min(start_date) else null end as `a`
,case when activity = 'b' then  min(start_date) else null end as `b`
,case when activity = 'c' then  min(start_date) else null end as `c`
,case when activity = 'd' then  min(start_date) else null end as `d`
group by 1,2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select id, type,
       max(case when activity = 'a' then start_date end) as a,
       max(case when activity = 'b' then start_date end) as b,
       max(case when activity = 'c' then start_date end) as c,
       max(case when activity = 'd' then start_date end) as d,
       max(case when activity = 'e' then start_date end) as e
from thistable
group by id, type;
```